# My Arduino Uno Wifi, stops responding to wifi

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

My new Arduino Uno Wifi, stops responding to wifi if left inactive. To be more specific, after 2-3 hours of no wifi usage:

1. I cannot access the build-in configuration page of the Arduino's wifi section
2. Loaded programs which use Wifi are not receiving any commands via my browser
3. loop() continues to run just fine

It somehow seems that the wifi section of my Uno Wifi "sleeps" after some arbitrary interval.

Using code to periodically reset the board (by sending HIGH to the reset pin of the board) did not solve the problem. As soon as the reset takes place, loop() starts executing just fine, but wifi connection is still impossible to obtain.

Things I usually do to gain access to my board AFTER wifi is lost:

1. Hard reset the board (unplug power and plug it again) -> almost always works
2. Try to access arduino from several different wifi devices hoping that the board somehow "wakes up" -> occasionally works but only after 4 or 5 minutes (sometimes hours) of failed attempts

My router seems to be fine. Another web server which I have set up in a wifi-connected laptop has had no hiccups (even after a long time of inactivity). Moreover I've never had any connection problems with my router so far.

This is giving me a hard time! Could anybody be of any help?

Is my Arduino Uno faulty?

Many thanks in advance

George

---

Here's my configuration:

Arduino Uno Wifi Developer edition (built-in wifi support)

Arduino IDE 1.8.0 (I'm using the Linux version installed on Ubuntu 12.04 )

I have already connected my arduino to my home network and gave it a static IP 192.168.2.50

WIFI mode: STA

Wifi channel: 1

SLIP status enabled

MQTT status disabled/disconnected

code:

```
int i=0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT); 
}

void loop() {

  if (i==1){
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    i=0;
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);
    i=1;
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: where's the code?

Comment: i know on esp8266-only sketches, i have to call wifi.disconnect() during boot, to flush out old connections, maybe you need something like that?

Comment: Hi and thanks for the comments. Patrick I believe code is irrelevant but I am adding it to the description. Dan, I think that wifi.disconnect() might also be  irrelevant because the problem occurs even if I do not use wifi from my code. (Remember that I cannot see the configuration page either). However I'll give it a try and come back with the results

Comment: unfortunately wifi.disconnect() did nothing to solve the wifi connectivity problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I have been a victim of an extreme ambiguity caused by the .org fork of arduino.

Arduino.cc and Arduino.org boards are NOT 100% compatible with each other.

To be more specific, the examples that come with the IDE (and are based on the the wifi shield of arduino.cc) DO NOT function with aruduino-uno-wifi (the one with the  embedded wifi section)

Apart from that, it seems that arduino-uno-wifi has firmware that is way behind the arduino.cc (in terms of features as well as code quality). This has frustrated several users as you can see here:

[Issue 2: Rename this fork and use less confusing versioning](https://github.com/arduino-org/Arduino/issues/2)

[Issue 10: Please stop doing this !](https://github.com/arduino-org/Arduino/issues/10)

[Issue 6: Remove old licenses from sample code comments and take credit for everything](https://github.com/arduino-org/Arduino/issues/6)

If you are interested of an arduino.org view of things visit here:
[The full story](http://www.arduino.org/blog/the-full-story-1)

All of the above is information which I wish I had when ordering my new ardnino-uno-wifi board.

Moreover it is relevant with the question I've asked, since it indicates that my problem is most probably a bug of the uno-wifi board, so I should file a bug report (and keep hoping) instead of trying to fix my code.